# How to set tooltip to highcharts legends?

Tags: highcharts

I was using highcharts for representing a log data, due to small space I have truncated the legends, but on mouse hovering over legends I need a tooltip to show the detailed legend value.

Comment: Hi @Venkatesh S and welcome to SO! To get the best feedback from the community, I recommend reading through this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Can you provide some code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, please share your example in the online code editor.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use labelFormatter of legend and use it to return some HTML content with title attribute which will have full name of the series. Checkout this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Saibabu276/e0f6rv5n/) for the same.

```
 legend: {
            useHTML: true,
    labelFormatter: function () {
        return '<span title="'+ this.name +'">' + this.name + '</span>' + ' (click to hide)';
    }
},
```

Plese upvote if this works for you.